# Issues with installing packages : theano , sklearn?

Tags: python3

How to install scipy, theano, sklearn for **python3.4**?

l've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-theano
```

but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-pip libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

There are extra packages because of the dependencies. Next, do this:

```
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn
sudo pip install theano
```

For the above command I am not sure if it's `theano` or `Theano`.

[source_1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html), [source_2](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html)